# Me da error 500 al intentar enviar formulario AYUDA!

Tags: php, html, formularios

soy nuevo en esto de los websites y no se como solucionar este error que tengo al enviar el formulario les dejo el código, los errores del servidor y demás información espero que me puedan ayudar.

Nota: Estoy usando Neubox como host. Url: https://neubox.com/

**HTML:**

```
<form name="formb" method="POST" action="sendform.php">
<input type="text" class="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombres"minlength="3" required>
<input type="text" class="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombres" minlength="3" required>
<select name="tipo" id="tipo" required>
  <option value="0">- Tipo -</option>
  <option value="1">Opcion1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion2</option>
</select>
<input type="email" class="text" name="correo" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
<textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ingresa la descripcion" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Formulario de comisiones(Preguntar)";

// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['nombre']) ||
!isset($_POST['apellido']) ||
!isset($_POST['tipo']) ||
!isset($_POST['correo']) ||
!isset($_POST['descripcion'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Apellido: " . $_POST['apellido'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Tipo de Comision: " . $_POST['tipo'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['correo'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['descripcion'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
?>
```

**Errores que muestra:**

[Tue Oct 23 23:05:52.030594 2018] [:error] [pid 1967456] [client 181.199.83.79:40752] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/ocatartc/public_html/sendform.php" is writeable by group, referer: https://ocatart.com/comisiones

***AGREGADO:***

Quería saber si al formulario se le puede agregar un input file para subir imagenes y como hacer que funcione en el mismo sendform.php y se suba a la carpeta /uploads intente con este tutorial pero genera el mismo error 500
url: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

**Update:**
Ya arregle lo de los permisos el sendform.php y funciona, el problema es que al correo no llega nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según esta respuesta solo tienes que cambiar los permisos:

> Change the file permissions from '0664' to '0644'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700821/public-index-php-is-writeable-by-group-in-laravel

Para modificar permisos desde Cpanel:

1. Ve a tu explorador de carpetas.
2. Ubica el archivo el cual quieres modificar.
3. Click derecho sobre el archivo y selecciona Modificar permisos
4. Modifica a tu antojo.

Comment: las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, lee [answer] y añade lo importante del enlace aqui y deja el link como referencia

Comment: además debes explicar por que el cambio de permisos es aplicable y necesario aqui

Comment: Perdona la ignorancia pero sabes como se cambian esos permisos en cpanel? agradecería que me ayudaras.

Comment: @luismiguelmoralespajaro dale editar a tu respuesta y coloca eso de los permisos ahi, las respuestas no van en los comentarios

Comment: he modificado la respuesta con los pasos para modificar los permisos desde cpanel.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! funciono pero ahora tengo otro problema.
Lo acabo de poner como Update en mi pregunta

Comment: verifica primero si es algo en el cpanel, prueba enviando el correo con valores fijos para descartar

Comment: en cpanel no hay errores de ningún tipo y no se que puede estar fallando también intente con otros códigos que encontré por ahí para probar y aun así no funcionan estoy considerando enviar un tiket al proveedor de hosting para descartar algún problema de ellos tambien.

Comment: ¿pero si creas un archivo php donde solo pruebas la funcion mail con valores fijos tampoco funciona?

Comment: si tampoco funciona